# DEVC++ Makefile.win has changed. Reload from disk? error

Tags: makefile, linker-errors, dev-c++

When I execute my code which includes 5 source files and 4 header files. It executes correctly at first. After executing again and again this window appears when program is executed. And indicates the line shown. I tried rebuild and I deleted the makefile but I cant fix this. [image]

Answer (score 0):

just close that tab and change your TDM-GCC from 64-bit to 32-bit

Answer (score -1):

just close the tab showing makefile.
It is adjacent to your main program.